# Laravel Forcing HTTPS with Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ssl, https, laravel

I have a site running Laravel 3 which needs to force https using the following rewrite rule in apache config:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This forces https correctly but all the Laravel routes return 'Not Found' (i.e. not hitting index.php), if I remove the rewrite rule everything works.

The .htaccess inside the /public folder is as normal for Laravel:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

# For all files not found in the file system, reroute the request to the
# "index.php" front controller, keeping the query string intact

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some hours debugging it seems simple now: my default-ssl config did not have the line

```
AllowOverride All
```

To enable the htaccess to be read

Comment: Great! Works for me.

Answer (score 5):

This .htaccess is working for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't for me

Comment: Working on `Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)`.

Comment: I solved it - was my oversight on the ssl config not allowing the htaccess to be read - thanks for your help though