# Dropbox App redirect_url in Vagrant - Non-local OAuth 2 redirect URIs may not start with "http:" or "javascript:"

Tags: php, api, vagrant, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying out my first Dropbox API integration project. My development environment is in Vagrant (`192.168.33.10`) and I use a hostname `ppt.dev` to access the site from my main machine. The problem is, Dropbox allow only `localhost` as redirect_uri for app in development or I need to give a URL with `https` as Redirect URI. If I give my development URI (image given below), I got this error.

Dropbox App error:

[image: Dropbox App Error]

I am not sure how to solve this problem. Is it possible I can enable `https` in my Vagrant (with Ubuntu 14.04) or I can do anything in [Dropbox App](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps) that will give me access to add development URI.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I solved with help of some content from other site.

> [The easiest and fastest way to do it would be to use those 4
>   lines](https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=421-ssl-certificate-in-vagrant/0)

```
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite property-ssl.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

And add these lines in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/property-ssl.conf`. Ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17901129/2627842)

```
<Directory /var/www/html/property/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Now in my development site can be accessed with `https` and I can add `https://ppt.dev/dropbox/callback` URL to dropbox app.